# Google Apps script to download files directly to drive using URL

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-apps-script

I have got unlimited storage space in my Google Drive. I'd like to download files from internet directly to Google Drive. Also I'd like to know whether it is possible to download torrents directly to Google Drive using the Google scripts. I'm trying Google scripts for the first time so I don't really know how to do this. While googling i had found lot of sites like bytesloader.com, filetodrive.thetimetube.com etc. but not sure about its reliability. So that why i'm looking for a Google App Script to do the same without any file size limit.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome, Google has an extension that can download a file directly to Google Drive: [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne). (See also: [Save Web Pages to your Google Drive](http://www.labnol.org/internet/save-web-pages-to-google-drive/27054/).)

If you are not using Chrome, you could use [Save Web Files](http://ctrlq.org/save/) to do the same.
However, it is not clear whether this site intercepts your Google Account credentials. *Caveat emptor*.

More information: [How to Download Files from the Internet to Google Drive Directly](http://www.techverse.net/download-web-internet-files-google-drive-directly/).

Comment: I have used Save to Google Drive before but i doesn't allow to download files greater than a 250MB (Not sure). Does the second method (ctrlq.com/save/) has any limit.